# How to convert seconds to minutes in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I get the input as a second from the user and I want to show it as minutes and second in the Grid. I know I have to use a method but I don't know how.

```
**SeizureViewModel**
   [Display(Name ="Seizure Time")]
        public int SeizureTime{ get; set; }

**AddSeizure View**
 @Html.BSMaterialTextBoxFor(model => model.SeizureTime, "", colCSS: "col-6")

**Show Seizure View**
@model PagedList<SeizureViewModell>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        @(Html.Grid(Model)
        .Name("epileptic seizures")
        .PKColumn(p => p.ID)
        .Columns(c =>
        {
            c.Add(a => a.SeizureTime);
           
        }).HasHeader(true)
        .HasFooter(true)
        .ToolbarButtons(b => { b.Add(GridButtonType.custom).CssClass("btn addseizure").Icon("fa-plus").Title("Add Epilectic Seizure"); })
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (SeizureTime/60).ToString()+":"+(SeizureTime%60).ToString()

Comment: Where do I need to write this code?

Comment: Where do you need to output minutes instead of seconds?

Comment: Use TimeSpan instead of int?

Comment: It worked thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In ViewModel , I added an another property to show the time the way I want to.

```
public string SeizureTimeStr
        {
            get
            {
                return (SeizureTime/ 60).ToString() +" Minutes"+ " " + (SeizureTime% 60).ToString()+" Seconds";

            }
        }
```

This is where I show the seizure time so I changed it as SeizureTimeStr in ShowSeizureView.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
        @(Html.Grid(Model)
        .Name("epileptic seizures")
        .PKColumn(p => p.ID)
        .Columns(c =>
        {
            c.Add(a => a.SeizureTimeStr);
           
        }).HasHeader(true)
        .HasFooter(true)
        .ToolbarButtons(b => { b.Add(GridButtonType.custom).CssClass("btn addseizure").Icon("fa-plus").Title("Add Epilectic Seizure"); })
        )
    </div>
```